# Multiple mounts on single partition, fresh install

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 120GB SSD and 1TB HDD in my computer. I will be formatting often as well as attempting to preserve my SSD from both large formats and unneeded in-system writes. After creating a successful filesystem structure from installation (and if need be post install configurations) that meets my needs, I will then be saving a copy of the two drivess via imaging in the event I need to restore "factory" settings without the lengthy process of re-installation.

- Both drives are empty so no care has to be taken in data preservation.
- I will be doing installation and if need be post configuration from within a live USB Ubuntu environment.
- I will be imaging both drives pre-boot to save to a separate 16GB flash drive.

Goal: I simply require 5 partitions total between the 2 drives.

SSD

- [ Partition 1 ][ 512 MB ][ EFI Filesystem ][ /boot ] - Grub
- [ Partition 2 ][ FILL ][ EXT4 ][ / ] - OS and dependencies

HDD

- [ Partition 1 ][ 512 GB ][ EXT4 ][ /home ]
- [ Partition 2 ][ 128 GB ][ EXT4 ][ /usr - /opt - /var ]
- [ Partition 3 ][ 16 GB ][ linux-swap ]
- [ Unallocated ][ FILL ]

(Possibly / Undecided)

16GB RAM

- [ Partition 1 ][ 4GB ][ TMPFS ][ /tmp ]
- [ Unallocated ][ FILL ]

Problem: In HDD - Partition 2 I require multiple mounts to be used in a single partition on the HDD with absolutely no direct unneeded write access on part of the HDD to SSD. The installer will only work with separate filesystems with separate partitions. I am attempting to both reduce space used and writes to the SSD while attempting to use the HDD for the more space and write intensive directories without the need for creating partitions costing performance.

Outcome: What I expect from a solution is the steps to finalizing allocation of the root `/` file structure on a single partition on the SSD while placing `/usr` `/opt` `/var` (for now) `/tmp` on the HDD in a single partition.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

should contain

```
UUID="Your unique partition UUID" /prt2 ext4 defaults 0 0
/prt2/usr /usr            none    bind              0       0
/prt2/opt /opt            none    bind              0       0
/prt2/var /var            none    bind              0       0
/prt2/tmp /tmp            none    bind              0       0
```